# Fetch data from List using iterator

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to fetch the data using List but by using iterator. It is displaying me the object. How can I fetch the data from it?

```
import java.util.*;
    class Getter_Setter
    {
        int id;
        String name;
        public List<Getter_Setter> buckets;
        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public int getId()
        {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id)
        {
            this.id=id;
        }
        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name=name;
        }
        public void setGetter_Setter(List<Getter_Setter> buck)
        {
            this.buckets=buck;
        }
    }
    class Simple
    {
        public static void main(String arg[])
        {
            run();
        }
        public static void run()
        {

            List<Getter_Setter> getList=sum();
            Iterator itr=getList.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(itr.next());
            }
        }
        public static List<Getter_Setter> sum()
        {
            List<Getter_Setter> list=new ArrayList<Getter_Setter>();
            Getter_Setter get=new Getter_Setter();
            get.setId(30);
            get.setName("Hanish");

            System.out.println(get.getId());
            System.out.println(get.getName());
            list.add(get);
            return  list;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Getter_Setter getterSetter = (Getter_Setter) itr.next()` then you can reference to getterSetter to access its data

Comment: Override `toString()` in `Getter_Setter`.

Comment: You could also override `Getter_Setter#toString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not Overridden any `toString()` method it's giving you object hash code 
you need to override this(end code snippet) to print things what you want to print from that class otherwise

the default `toString()` implementation of the `Object` class, that is:

```
  public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

gets called when you pass object in `println()` method

```
 class Getter_Setter {
        int id;
        String name;
        public List < Getter_Setter > buckets;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void setGetter_Setter(List < Getter_Setter > buck) {
            this.buckets = buck;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Getter_Setter [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", buckets="
                    + buckets + "]";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sum` methods returns a typed `List<Getter_Setter>`, so you can get a strongly-typed iterator from it :

```
List<Getter_Setter> getList = sum();
Iterator itr<Getter_Setter> = getList.iterator();
```

Which allows you to directly retrieve `Getter_Setter` elements, on which you can call the `getId()` and `getName()` methods  :

```
Iterator<Getter_Setter> itr = getList.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Getter_Setter item = its.next();
    System.out.println(item.getId());
    System.out.println(item.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the foreach style to iterate. It is a generic typed iteration method. It automatically makes the objects into your generic type for you. i.e obj to instance of Getter_Setter.

```
public static void run() {

        List < Getter_Setter > getList = sum();


       foreach(Getter_Setter g: getList){

          System.out.println(g.getId());

         System.out.println(g.getName());
          } 
    }
```